How to install Epson L3215 in Ubuntu 22.04
I am unable to install Epson L3215 printer in Ubuntu 22.04. Please tell the due process.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You have not provided us enough information about your printer and computer to answer the question. Have you connected the printer to your computer? How are the two connected, USB, Ethernet cable, or WiFi? When you go to the Settings app and click on the Printers tab on the left panel, do you see the printer detected? If the printer is detected, click on the three dots next to it and select Printing Options. From there are you able to print a test page? Edit your question above and add all these information.

Try the following:
Navigate to this page and the file will be downloaded epson-printer-utility_1.1.1-1lsb3.2_amd64
https://www.doctorimpresora.com/epson/epson-printer-utility_1.1.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.html
Install it via apt
sudo apt install ~/Downloads/epson-printer-utility_1.1.1_1lsb3.2_amd64

You will be asked for your password to acquire the privileges needed to install software on your system.
Navigate to this page and the file will be downloaded iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz
https://www.doctorimpresora.com/epson/epson_iscan_bundle_2.30.4.x64_deb.html
Change to the folder where you downloaded this scanner driver bundle,extract it and install all components with
tar xaf iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz
cd iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb
sudo chmod +x install.sh
./install.sh

In a terminal window.
You will be asked for your password to acquire the privileges needed to install software on your system.
